# Does Apple allows restricting In-App Purchase DLC Non-Consumable Content to one device?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I have been reading the review guideline: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

I see section about for subscription its has to be available for all iOS devices of a single user:

Content subscriptions using IAP must last a minimum of 7 days and be available to the user from all of their iOS devices.

But does that apply to Non-Consumable Content as well?
I am worry Apple will reject our app because of this reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are afraid Apple will reject your app because you use non-consumable content on only one device?

One of my project has in-app purchases only for 1 device. The app is already 6 years continuously reviewed and successfully deployed. Believe me, this is not an issue aslong you are not using a subscription.

The only problem you are facing is someone can buy the DLC also on a other device and it will auto unlock as it has already been purchased with the same Apple ID. There are ways to prevent this by securing your app via a database.

Comment: @rwzdoom You just saved my day!  How did you prevent DLC being used by other device?  The only way I can think of now is to track their VendorID and tie the VendorID with the DLC receipt transaction id...

Comment: Your welcome @KingChan . We created some UDID from the device and the account of the user is only accessible per 1 device.

Comment: @rwzdoom I wonder how do you handle multiple account (i.e. Facebook login)?  If the user user login with different facebook account, then is a completely different account with DLC they should be able to restore?

Comment: We don't accept switching accounts and retrieving a DLC (it's 1 user 1 buy, not 2 users 1 buy way). Why would anyone want to switch Facebook accounts and use the same DLC?